# Maven Install but will not execute

Tags: java, maven, classnotfoundexception

In my my pom.xml file I have:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, in my source I have the line :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver;
```

When I run mvn install, all of the code compiles perfectly. However, when I run mvn exec:java, I get a class not found error -- org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver can not be found.

Why would I be able to install code and not be able to run it? Thanks.

I am using org.codehaus.mojo exec plugin.

Not working configuration:

```xml
<mainClass>myMainClass</mainClass>
<executableDependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
     <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
</executableDependency>
```

Comment: What does your configuration for the `exec` plugin look like? According to the documentation, the enclosing project's dependencies should be on the classpath.

Comment: I just have the name of my main class <mainClass>myMainClass</mainClass> Maybe you could post as an answer what it should look like? Or link me? Thanks.

Comment: Try running it from the command line instead. `java -cp hadoop-core-1.1.0.jar Main` and see what happens. You will need all the dependency jars there for the `cp` option with semi-colons separating and full path info.

Comment: @LeeMeador I can't really try that because I have a lot of other jars and dependencies.

Comment: Use `mvn -X` to log a bunch of stuff that will include a nicely formatted classpath. You might see the problem looking at it but you can cut and paste it into a shell script or batch file to try the command line thing.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html)

Simply add this to your pom.xml

```xml
<configuration>
      <executable>java</executable>
      <arguments>
        <argument>-Dmyproperty=myvalue</argument>
        <argument>-classpath</argument>
        <!-- automatically creates the classpath using all project dependencies,
             also adding the project build directory -->
        <classpath/>
        <argument>com.example.Main</argument>
        ...
      </arguments>
</configuration>
```